# C++ endl with constants

Tags: c++, endl

I am just trying to familiarise myself with the basics of C++ moving from Java. I just wrote this functionality abstinent program and am coming across an error`test.cpp:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘<<’ token` and I am not sure why.

Anybody care to explain why `endl` is not working with constants? The code is below.

```
//Includes to provide functionality.
#include <iostream>

//Uses the standard namespace.
using namespace std;

//Define constants.
#define STRING "C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler";

//Main function.
int main()
{
  string enteredString;

  cout << STRING << endl;
  cout << "Please enter a String:" << endl;
  cin >> enteredString;
  cout << "Your String was:" << endl;
  cout << enteredString << endl;

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: The snippet above does have this: `#include <string>`. Does your original code have it?

Comment: Say `#include <string>` at the top of your file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `;` in your preprocessor definition. Note that `#DEFINE STRING x` just copies the whole x-statement (including the `;`) into the place where it's referenced.

Also, a preprocessor constant isn't a language constant. You should use `const string STRING("C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler");`

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, rookie error. Oh, would you happen to know why only the first word of my string is printed? Thanks.

Comment: @VisionIncision: `cin >> enteredString` only reads one word. To read the whole line use `getline(cin, enteredString)`.

Answer (score 8):

Your `#define` has a semicolon at the end. That becomes *part of the macro*, so the pre-processed code looks like this:

```
cout << "C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler"; << endl;
```

Remove the semicolon and you should be fine.

---

**PS:** It's usually a better idea to use real constants for this rather than relying on the preprocessor:

```
const char *STRING = "C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler";
```

Comment: he also needs to include <string> for "string enteredString;" to compile

Comment: @Peter: actually many implementations of `<iostream>` will include it for you.

Comment: @KillianDS: You shouldn't rely on that for portable code, though.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a secmi-colon at the end of your `#define` - this will be substituted into your code, giving.

`cout << "C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler"; << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a semi colon after STRING. Remove it and give it a try...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` in the `STRINGS` definition

Answer (score 1):

Remove **;** from

```
#define STRING "C++ is working on this machine usig the GCC/G++ compiler"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` at the end of `#define STRING` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

## define is a preprocessor directive. This replaces everything that follows the defined macro, in this case STRING. So, remove the last semicolon (;) that puts an end-of-statement marker while being expanded in the offending line.